# Setting variables in Xcode debug session

Tags: xcode, optimization, xcode4, xcode4.3

I want to optimize the algorithm that relies on several variables for configuration. User interface doesn't unclude this variables; actually, after the optimization, they'll become constants. Is there a way to manually set these variables between tests without re-launching an application in Xcode?